# Protect the content of External Disk/USB Storage

Tags: disk-encryption, usb

Due to certain circumstances, we are forced to keep some copyrighted data in an external hard disk. due to privacy concerns, we want to allow this data to be accessed only from a trusted/office provided device. if this external disk is connected to a personal or untrusted device, data should not be accessible.

we tried bitlocker, but it allows you to access data from external disk by connecting it to your personal PC,  if you know the password.

Not sure if a certificate based encryption of external hard disk is possible, where the decryption or unlocking of drive is possible only from a PC where the certificate is stored.

Any other solution available to address this problem ?

Comment: This is usually accomplished by an agent on approved devices that accesses a protected portion of the external drive (or the whole drive is protected). Only the agent can open the protected portion.

Comment: any product or solution available that can achieve this ?

Comment: Bitlocker + TPM unlock will effectively bind it to that computer?

Comment: There are lots, actually, but if you are looking for a product/solution, I can migrate this to the site that handles that sort of thing.